# Calculation Inductance Voltage in book 'Practical Electronics for Inventors'

Tags: voltage, inductance

I'm curious is calculation in screen right?

[image: Figure 2.134 of 4th edition, page 139]

<sub>Source: Practical Electronics for Inventors, 4th edition, page 139</sub>

I assume Voltage from 2-3 sec must be -0.2V, because dI/dt=(-1)-1=-2A, not -1A.

Am I right?

Comment: Simply change the current axis from 1A...-1A into 0.5A....-0.5A.  Also ractical Electronics for Inventors (3rd Ed) is a very bad book throw it away (too many errors).
http://mhprofessional.com/downloads/products/0071771336/0071771336_scherzmonk_errata.pdf  Here you have additional (very long) errata. https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=967A90CA47FD025B!172&ithint=file%2c.pdf&app=WordPdf&authkey=!ACEbpvA4f9gUlxc from here http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/practical-electronics-for-inventors-3rd/150/ and here http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/relative-voltage-point.113589/

Comment: Thanks, G36. What book do you recommend?

Comment: And it's 4th ed of book =)

Comment: If you already have it, simply use the errata (unofficial one) and you should be just fine. And if you will have still any doubts ask about it on forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. The X-axis is missing 0 to 0.5s so the calculation should be:

$$ V = L \frac {di}{dt} = 0.1 \frac {1A}{0.5s} = 0.2~V $$

From 2 to 3 s it should be:

$$ V = L \frac {di}{dt} = 0.1 \frac {-2A}{1s} = -0.2~V $$

Skepticism is healthy!

Answer (score 0):

May be you are right, may be your wrong.

What is pretty sure is that the book is at least ambiguous.

The very first time division on graph - from 0 to 1s- is a half long respect to the other ones.

So if read the graph you are right but if you look at it you can guess that is an even waveform extending simmetrically before 0s mark with the same slope as the other transitions

Comment: carloc, Thanks for reply. If I extending plot simmetrically before 0s graph, peak to peak Current will be 2A anyway and changing 2A/s. So in this case Voltage must be 0.2 in both.